# Online Math Colloquia

Tags: big-list, online-resources

One of the formative experiences of my undergraduate education in math was attending department math talks. These were usually aimed at general faculty members, so they went well over my head at the beginning. Still, I found the experience helpful at giving me a sense of vocabulary, snippets of ideas, and a sense of the diversity of areas of math. A bit like immersion language learning.

I have a student who I would like to encourage to attend similar talks, but we don't offer them where I am. Normally I'd send them to a nearby school to attend their math talks, but the pandemic leaves things quite uncertain at the moment. Are there any online general seminars I can point my student to?

Comment: This is what I would counsel students to do as well when they were still deciding on a major or a topic for possible future study:  just go to department colloquia that sounded interesting, just to find out what people in the field are currently working on.  You don't have to understand all of a talk (or even _much_ of one) for a while, but you will get used to the culture and start getting ideas about what might be interesting to pursue further (or what you might not care all that much about). [continued]

Comment: [continuing]  As for what's online, it's an embarrassment of riches.  I just searched on "mathematics colloquia" on Google and found that a _lot_ of universities post videos nowadays.  Since March 2020, many of them require Zoom to view, but others are more generally accessible.  Before that time, most will link to YouTube or some other playable format.  So it may be better to include some general branch of math in the search; it may not pay to be _too_ specific, as that may lead mostly to very specialized talks.  One needs to be prepared time just skimming through lists of talks.

Comment: Many of the research centers and institutions also post videos of their colloquia and workshops, but this may be more advanced/specialized than what you wish to direct your student towards.